# É má prática deixar uma Model inteira em Cache no IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cache

Em uma aplicação utilizo dezendas de vezes um código como

```
var cliente = db.Clientes.Find(id);
```

Então por isso criei uma controller que me retorna:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = (10 * 60 * 60), VaryByParam = "id")]
    public static Cliente ClienteInfo(int id)
    {
        using (WMBContext db = new WMBContext())
        {
            return db.Clientes.Find(id);
        }
    }
```

Ficou extremamente rápido, porém estou gravando a model inteira em cache, imaginando que id diferentes serão em torno de 300, então serão 300 x Model em em memória no IIS.
Lembro que antigamente não era recomendável armazenar RecordSets inteiros em Session, em teoria não estou fazendo isso?

**Agora não sei o que é melhor, buscar 6000x no banco de dados ou armazenar 300model na memória.**

Existe como verificar a memória utilizada no cache? ficará vinculada ao pool? (ainda não está em produção o código)

*Edit OBS:* Essa model tem relacionamento com outras model e possui mais de 30 propriedades.

Comment: não vejo como má pratica, caso à memoria da maquina onde o IIS não seja suficiente, você ainda pode mudar o provider do seu Cache. te aconselho a dá uma olhada em [RedisOutputCacheProvider](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.RedisOutputCacheProvider/)

Comment: mais uma coisa, uma cache de 10 horas talvez não seja o ideal. e tente invalidar o cache sempre que o registro vier a ser alterado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que está disponível [aqui](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/757201/A-Beginners-Tutorial-for-Understanding-and-Imple), o Outputcache armazena apenas o retorno de sua action (seja html, json, etc) e não objetos.

No seu caso, você está evitando uma consulta no banco de dados (que sempre é bom, ainda por cima utilizando entity, que utiliza bastante recursos de memória).

Sempre que for possível pela lógica de sua aplicação, utilize o Outputcache para diminuir uso de resources do servidor.

Sobre [alterar os opções](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623405/it-is-possible-to-know-the-outputcache-size-in-asp-net-mvc-3) do Outputcache ou [monitorar sua utilização de memória](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/caching).